# SQL - Concat in where clause with IN

Tags: sql

I'm trying use `IN` to query multiple columns.  If I use "=", I return rows (see example) but I would like to query multiple.

need query table to return rows A12345 and B98765 but not C00000

```
column1 | column2
A         12345
B         98765
C         00000
```

This works

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE (column1,column2) = ('A',12345)
```

This does not work.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE (column1,column2) IN (('A',12345),('B',98765))
```

Here is error:

```
Error: SQL0104N  An unexpected token "," was found following ",".  Expected tokens may include:  "AT MICROSECONDS MICROSECOND SECONDS SECOND MINUTES MINUTE HOURS".  SQLSTATE=42601
 (State:42601, Native Code: FFFFFF98)
```

I've tried several variations of parenthesis, commas's, etc and can't get it to work.  Is it possible to do this and if so can you provide the syntax.

thanks

Comment: What database server is it? MSSQL or DB2? Sounds like DB2.

Answer (score 0):

DB2 9.7 onwards:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE (column1, column2) IN (VALUES ('A', 12345), ('B', 98765))
```

One solution is to use a temp table:

```
create table #tmp
(
    col1 varchar(2),
    col2 int
);

insert into #tmp (col1, col2)
values ('A', 12345), ('B', 98765)

SELECT t.* FROM TABLE t
JOIN #tmp ON #tmp.col1 = t.column1 and #tmp.col2 = t.column2
```

You haven't stated your RDBMS, but have you tried:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE (column1, column2) IN ('A', 12345) 
OR (column1, column2) IN ('B', 98765)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your data, this might be workable:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE T
JOIN (
   SELECT 'A' COL1, 12345 COL2
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'B', 98765 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'C', 44365) AS Matches
ON T.column1 = Matches.COL1
AND T.column2 = Matches.COL2
```

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be easy and should have known this.

SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE CONCAT(column1, column2) IN ('A12345','B98765')